# how do I compare the changes with my current non-commited state with the previous commited state?

Tags: git

**how do I compare the changes with my current non-commited state with the previous commited state `a88a9`?**

this is my current git status, there has been changes since my last commit

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit
```

how do I compare the changes with my current non-commited state with the previous commited state `a88a9`?

This is my commits

```
$ git log --pretty=oneline
a88a937d3154291d77156fce2e6c3a0b932c4e6d add the --done! part in the index.html
3a5c6a881a67664b365a8eddb1c6f0ddd44099b6 css for .priority-btn
32365dfdf27264691929eac8b5d1e9260a367802 css for .edit-btn
e3d040a11e1363447ad8953453c4284c9dd097eb remove TodoMVC readme
dd721f439355b3aa6ce1add52e2b35e51dec5cdb init
$
```

this does with a diff on one commit with another, which I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191282/how-to-see-the-changes-between-two-commits-without-commits-in-between), but I want to compare with my current non committed state.

```
$ git diff a88a937d 3a5c6a8
```

Am I right to say `HEAD` is the current working state or is it the last commit?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how show the diff from my current working directory and my last commit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035068/how-show-the-diff-from-my-current-working-directory-and-my-last-commit)

Comment: this is what I use `git diff HEAD`
from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39460097/how-to-see-whats-changed-between-last-commit-and-nowafter-making-some-changes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just do `git diff a88a9` it will compare commit `a88a9` to what you currently have local in your repo.

Comment: see my comment above also -  this is what I use git diff HEAD from here